# Проблема вывода двунаправленного списка(а также возможна проблема в методе Swap(), хочу заменить в нём элемент, на новый)

Tags: c++, вывод, двусвязный-список

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node *prev, *next;
};

class List
{
    Node *head, *tail;
    int count;

public:
    List ();
   ~List ();
    Node *GetElem (int);
    void DellAll ();
    void Dell (int pos);
    void Insert (int pos = 0);
    void TailAdd (int n);
    void HeadAdd (int n);
    void Print (int pos);
    Node *Swap (int pos, Node * elem);
    void Print ();
};

List::List ()
{
    head = tail = NULL;
    count = 0;
}

List::~List ()
{
    DellAll ();
}

void
List::HeadAdd (int n)
{
    Node *temp = new Node;
    temp->prev = NULL;
    temp->data = n;
    temp->next = head;

    if (head != 0)
        temp->prev = temp;
    if (count == 0)
        head = tail = NULL;
    else
        head = temp;
    count++;
}

void
List::TailAdd (int n)
{
    Node *temp = new Node;
    temp->next = NULL;
    temp->data = n;
    temp->prev = tail;
    
    if (tail != 0)
        temp->next = temp;
    if (count == 0)
        head = tail = temp;
    else
        tail = temp;
    count++;
}

void
List::Insert (int pos)
{
    if (pos == 0)
    {
        cout << "Enter a position";
        cin >> pos;
    }
    if (pos < 1 || pos > count + 1)
    {
      return;
    }
    if (pos == count + 1)
    {
        int data;
        cout << "Enter a new data:";
        cin >> data;
        TailAdd (data);
        return;
    }
    else if (pos == 1)
    {
      int data;
      cout << "Enter a new data:";
      cin >> data;
      HeadAdd (data);
      return;
    }
    int i = 1;
    Node *Ins = head;
    while (i < pos)
    {
        Ins = Ins->next;
        i++;
    }

    Node *PrevIns = Ins->prev;
    Node *temp = new Node;
    cout << "Enter a new data:";
    cin >> temp->data;
    
    if (PrevIns != 0 && count != 1)
        PrevIns->next = temp;

    temp->next = Ins;
    temp->prev = PrevIns;
    Ins->prev = temp;
    count++;
}

void
List::Print ()
{
    if (count != 0)
    {
        Node *temp = head;
        cout << "( ";
        while (temp->next != 0)
        {
            cout << temp->data << ", ";
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        cout << temp->data << " )\n";
    }
}

void
List::Dell (int pos)
{
  if (pos == 0)
    {
      cout << "Enter a position";
      cin >> pos;
    }

  if (pos < 1 || pos > count)
    {
      return;
    }

  int i = 1;

  Node *Del = head;
  while (i < pos)
    {
      Del = Del->next;
      i++;
    }


  Node *PrevDel = Del->prev;
  Node *AfterDel = Del->next;

  if (PrevDel != 0 && count != 1)
    PrevDel->next = AfterDel;

  if (AfterDel != 0 && count != 1)
    AfterDel->prev = PrevDel;


  if (pos == 1)
    head = AfterDel;
  if (pos == count)
    tail = PrevDel;

  delete Del;

  count--;
}

void
List::DellAll ()
{

  while (count != 0)
    Dell (1);
}

void
List::Print (int pos)
{

  if (pos < 1 || pos > count)
    {
      return;
    }

  Node *temp;

  if (pos <= count / 2)
    {

      temp = head;
      int i = 1;

      while (i < pos)
    {
      temp = temp->next;
      i++;
    }
    }
  else
    {
      temp = tail;
      int i = 1;

      while (i <= count - pos)
    {
      temp = temp->prev;
      i++;
    }
    }
  cout << pos << " element: ";
  cout << temp->data << endl;
}

Node *
List::GetElem (int pos)
{
  Node *temp = head;


  if (pos < 1 || pos > count)
    {
      return 0;
    }

  int i = 1;

  while (i < pos && temp != 0)
    {
      temp = temp->next;
      i++;
    }

  if (temp == 0)
    return 0;
  else
    return temp;
}

Node *
List::Swap (int pos, Node * elem)
{
  Node *temp = head;


  if (pos < 1 || pos > count)
    {
      return 0;
    }

  int i = 1;

  while (i < pos && temp != 0)
    {
      temp = temp->next;
      i++;
    }

  if (temp == 0)
    return 0;
  else
    temp = elem;
  return temp;
}

int
main ()
{
  List L;
  const int n = 10;
  int a[n] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    if (i % 2 == 0)
      L.HeadAdd (a[i]);
    else
      L.TailAdd (a[i]);
  cout << "List L:\n";
  L.Print ();

  cout << endl;
  cin.get ();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы бы хоть отступы починили. И так простыня кода, да ещё и отступы такие, что читать вообще невозможно.

Answer (score 1):

Вывод у вас правильный. Ошибки у вас при добавлении элементов в список.
В  функции добавления в начало вы создаете элемент, а потом начинаете творить непотребное. Если список не пустой, первый элемент закольцовывается сам на себя. При том, что при проходе по списку окончание прохода у вас проверяется на значение `NULL`. Далее если в списке не было элементов - вы просто выкидываете только что созданный элемент в никуда.

```
List::HeadAdd (int n)
{
    Node *temp = new Node;  // создали элемент, всё хорошо
    temp->prev = NULL;
    temp->data = n;
    temp->next = head;

    if (head != 0)   // первый элемент закольцовывается сам на себя
        temp->prev = temp; 
    if (count == 0)
        head = tail = NULL;  // потеря только что созданного элемента
    else
        head = temp;
```

То же самое в функции `TailAdd()` - последний элемент закольцовывается сам на себя. В принципе так тоже можно, но тогда при проходе по списку, нужно проверять конец списка по признаку `p->next == p`. Но зачем? Проще искать `NULL`

```
List::TailAdd (int n)
{
    Node *temp = new Node;
    temp->next = NULL;
    temp->data = n;
    temp->prev = tail;
    
    if (tail != 0)
        temp->next = temp; // закольцовка на себя
```

В функции `Dell()` вы не полностью отработали ситуацию удаления первого и последнего элемента.

```
List::Dell (int pos)
{
    ....
    Node *PrevDel = Del->prev;
    Node *AfterDel = Del->next;
    if (PrevDel != 0 && count != 1)
        PrevDel->next = AfterDel;
    if (AfterDel != 0 && count != 1)
        AfterDel->prev = PrevDel;
// а если это первый элемент списка? - вы забыли о AfterDel->prev
// а если это последний элемент списка? - вы забыли о PrevDel->next
    if (pos == 1)
        head = AfterDel;
    if (pos == count)
        tail = PrevDel;
```

Функция `Swap()` тоже странная какая-то. По сути, вам нужно поменять между собой **значения** элементов. Сами элементы менять не надо, указатели переприсваивать не надо. А у вас в конце трэш - вы просто одному указателю присваиваете другой. Если это был элемент не из списка, то вы просто теряете всё, что было в списке после присваиваемого. А если меняете два элемента из списка между собой - то теряете всё, что было между ними. И т.д., то есть получаете множество спецэффектов. Ну и условие `if (temp == 0) return 0;` никогда не выполняется, т.к. уже сделана проверка на попадания элемента в диапазон списка.

```
Node *
List::Swap (int pos, Node * elem)
{
  temp = // находим искомый элемент списка
  if (temp == 0)  
    return 0;  // никогда не выполняется
  else
    temp = elem;  // дичь !!!
  return temp;
}
```

Ну и несколько замечаний по коду.
У вас много где повторяется код по вводу позиции или значения. Раз код повторяется - вынесите его в отдельную функцию. И потом осуществлять ввод элемента и добавлять элемент в список - две разные сущности, по-нормальному их следует осуществлять последовательно, а не одну в другой. Т.е. сначала отработали ввод элемента или позиции, а потом выполняете функцию вставки.

```
List::Insert (int pos)
{
    if (pos == 0)
    {
        cout << "Enter a position";
        cin >> pos;
    }
    if (pos == count + 1)
    {
        int data;
        cout << "Enter a new data:";
        cin >> data;
```

С точки зрения производительности кода в функции `DellAll()` проще пройти циклом по списку и удалить все элементы, чем каждый раз вызывать `Dell()`, выполняя кучу проверок и переприсваивания указателей.